# Get ID of one of multiple buttons in HTML form in Django

Tags: jquery, python, html, django, forms

I'm using Django as the underlying FSM that powers a tracking website. I'm at the point where I want to allow user to change the state of the machine. The state is represented as a `django-fsm` field, essentially a CharField with some logic hacked on top of it.

In order to allow the users to pick the next state my initial approach was to show a multiple choice field (dropdown menu) that would have grayed out the states that are innaccessible from the current state. I couldn't find a good way to do that, and it was not very user friendly (although I'm still intrigued by a solution to the problem). For all those reasons, I went with plan B:

Have a form with multiple buttons, one for each state that we can go to. Something like this:

```
<form action="{% url 'tracking:order_detail' order.id %}" method="POST">
        <div id="buttons">
            <input id="3.4" type="submit" class="f" name="action" value="Some State">
            <input id="3.5" type="submit" class="f" name="action" value="Another State">
            <div style="clear:both"></div><!-- Need this to have the buttons actually inside div#buttons -->
        </div>
</form>
```

Now my question is: As the value I would like something that's human readable, but from Django I would like to retrieve an actual state value, which I've placed in the ID field, say "3.4". Looking at the form data in Django, all I can do is something along the lines of:

```
if request.method == "POST":
     action = request.POST.get('action')
```

But that will give me "Another State". There is no access to the `id` field. Looking at the [form specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4) I couldn't find another suitable field. Any ideas on how I can go about this.

Comment: I think the way forward will to use a hidden element and then set its value based on the clicked button

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qGwCE/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the input name as value

```
<form action="{% url 'tracking:order_detail' order.id %}" method="POST">
        <div id="buttons">
            <input type="submit" class="f" name="action:3.4" value="Some State">
            <input type="submit" class="f" name="action:3.5" value="Another State">
            <div style="clear:both"></div><!-- Need this to have the buttons actually inside div#buttons -->
        </div>
</form>
```

in python

```
if 'action:3.4' in request.POST:
    action = '3.4'
...
```

if you get a lot of actions you can search for the actions in the POST keys.

```
action = None
for key in request.POST.keys():
    if key.startswith('action:'):
        action = key[7:]
        break
```